# Qemu with TinyCoreLinux - networking

Tags: networking, qemu, tinycore

My host OS is Windows 7 ( IP: 192.168.0.25 ) and I have Qemu on it. I start TinyCore Linux on Qemu.

I want to see the address, for example 192.168.0.40, when I execute command `ifconfig` in TinyCore.

When I started qemu by command `qemu-system-i386.exe -cdrom C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Core-11.1.iso` and execute command `ifconfig` I see 2 interfaces: eth0 ( 10.0.2.15 ) and lo ( 127.0.0.1 ) on TinyCore.

When I started qemu by command `qemu-system-i386.exe -cdrom C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Core-11.1.iso -netdev user,id=xyz,net=192.168.0.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.0.40` and execute command `ifconfig` I see only 1 interface: lo ( 127.0.0.1 ) on TinyCore.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You still need to provide `device` when using `-netdev` (ie. `-netdev ...` and `-device` is extended syntax on `-nic ...`. See https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/invocation.html#hxtool-5

Thus you need something like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda linux.img -boot n -device e1000,netdev=n1 \
-netdev user,id=n1,tftp=/path/to/tftp/files,bootfile=/pxelinux.0
```

And... If you would upgrade to Windows 10, you could use acceleration for your QEMU not to be so slow. (Just a tip.)